How to combine SwiftData models and Decodables into a single type
I am working on building an application in swift that monitors devices using SwiftData and an api. The api returns two separate types: Device and Alert that are related, and I would like to store them using swift data, but would like to avoid coupling modelContext and @Query with the swift implementation of the API client.
A single device can have multiple alerts, an alert can only have one device.
@Model
final class Device: Decodable, Identifiable {
 @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
 @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Alert.device) public var alerts: [Alert] = []

 var latitude: Double 
 var longitude: Double
 var name: String
}


@Model
final class Alert: Decodable, Identifiable {
 @Attribute(.unique) var id: String

 var device: Device
 var title: String
 var body: String
 var createdAt: Date
 var expire: Date 
 var code: Int 
}

As for the api client, you can fetch the devices and alerts, but they come from separate endpoints.

final class APIClient {

 urlSession: URLSession

 
 func getDevices() async throws -> [Device]? {
  // logic to get devices (not including alerts)
  
 }

 func getAlerts() async throws -> [Alert]? {
  // logic to get alerts (each alert references device by name)
 }
}

A possible workaround for this is to create an intermediate struct, that doesn't conform to anything needed by @Model, but I'd rather keep the implementation clean and have a single type for storing in swiftdata and decoding from the api. Is there a way to accomplish this? Every example I've seen online thus far doesn't document use cases with Decodable types & models with relationships.
I tried creating intermediate models, but this just results in hard to follow and document code.

Use a specific public init(from decoder: Decoder)  to make your @Model Decodable.
Search SO, there are many posts on this subject.

I would go with an interim structure type that you use for decoding the API response but I would not use it as a property type in the model but rather have a convert/init method that maps the struct properties to the model properties. This way you separate the design from the rest api from your own design making future changes easier and a struct type is also much better if working with asynchronous code where you need to pass the data across actor boundaries.

@JoakimDanielson This is what I've decided to go with. The fact Apple does not provide a streamlined way to handle this or clear documentation is crazy. 99% of the use case for swiftdata is to cache data from an api. With all the other features swift includes you would think making the response type and swift data models easily compatible would be one of them.
